# Unload even on my form?

Tags: vb.net

I want to run a subroutine to clear some things up when the user exits the application. I tried looking for a Form_Unload event or anything similar, is there a way to do this?

I open a database connection on `Form_Load`, and would like to close it when the user exits the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, you should try not to hang on a connection for the lifetime of an application. You should open and close it as needed. If you don't want to close and reopen it as a performance optimization, you don't need to worry about it. Connection pooling for the database driver should handle that.

Anyway, you don't really need to close the connection if the process is going to end. The acquired resources will get released automatically.

If you want to execute code as the form gets closed, you can handle its `FormClosing` event. If you want the code to execute after a form is closed, handle its `FormClosed` event.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Closing and Closed are obsolete, FormClosing and FormClosed are their replacements.

Answer (score 2):

Use the FormClosing event.  The MSDN Library article [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx).  Poke around a bit more, these are the kind of events you need to know pat to do any kind of Windows Forms programming.